# PC-lint configuration for an arm target

Tags: arm, pc-lint

I tried to follow the documentation ( PC-lint.pdf ) and update the option.int file by adding the following options.

```
-ecpu=cortexm4f  -thumb    -thumb_lib
--short.enum     -align4   --no_commons
-no_alternative_tokens     -asm3g
-perprocess_assembly_files -nostartfiles
-globalcheck=normal        -globalcheck_qualifiers
--prototype_errors         -Wformat
-Wimplicit-int  -Wshadow   -Wtrigraphs
-Wundef         -reject_duplicates
-c             -list       -Olink
-Ointerproc    -Omax       -dwarf2
-G             -Dtviibe2m  -DCPU_BOARD_REVC
-D__ghs__      -D__GHS__   -DCY_USE_PSVP=0
-Dcyt2b9       -Ospeed     -OI
-fsingle
```

But I have an error 72 Wrong option on all new options.
Was not able to interpret an option. The option is given in String.

How can I solve this problem?

I try to use an existing configuration for a POWERPC target and change it for an ARM target and adding more options